# SPServices GetListItems don't work most of time

Tags: javascript, jquery, spservices

I'm using SPService in a list for take some information from an other list.

It works just sometimes... I need to refresh lot of time before it works ....

Here is my code :

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/0.7.1a/jquery.SPServices-0.7.1a.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("getToolInfo(807)");




function getToolInfo(lastID) {

    var CamlQuery = "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ID'/><Value Type='Counter'>" + lastID + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query>";
    var CamlViewFields = "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='ID' /><FieldRef Name='Title' /></ViewFields>";

  // this let me know that the function is getting called and passed the correct parameter value
  alert('function called and passed last ID of : ' + lastID);
  $().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: true,
    listName: "{D28F8F6B-9EFD-4FCA-9A2E-3A419EFCF637}",
    CAMLViewFields: CamlViewFields,
    CAMLQuery: CamlQuery,
      completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                    alert(xData.responseText);
                    console.log( xData.responseText );
                    $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() { 
                            //here is where we are reading the field values and putting them in JavaScript variables
                            //notice that when we read a field value there is an "ows_" in front of the internal field name.
                            //this is a SharePoint Web Service quirk that you need to keep in mind. 
                            //so to read a field it is ALWAYS $(this).attr("ows_<internal field name>");

                            //get the title field (Speaker's Name)
                            var ID=($(this).attr("ows_ID"));
                           alert(ID);
                            //get the blog url, SharePoint stores a url in the form of <url><comma><description>
                            //We only want the <url>. To accomplish this we use the javascript "split" function
                            //which will turn <url><comma><description> into an array where the first element [0]
                            //is the url.   Catch all that? if you didn't this is another reason you should be
                            //a developer if you are writing JavaScript and jQuery :)


                        });                
                    }

        });

}
```

The first alert : alert('function called and passed last ID of : ' + lastID);
work all the time.

The second alert : alert(xData.responseText); work 1 in 5 time

And the last alert : alert(ID); work 1 in 8 time .....

And i really don't know why or how to fix it ....
And it works only on IE and chrome not in firefox ...

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

I've had issues in the past with `alert(xData.responseText);` not doing anything.  Try changing it up to `alert(xData.responseXML.xml);`.

Also maybe try setting `async` to false.

I'd also try utilizing the document.ready function instead of `_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    getToolInfo(807);
});
```

Comment: I tryed to change async to false and it's the same.

Comment: edited with another option

Comment: finally I restart the server and it works !!!! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have `async: true`. What happens is that the code in the completefunc is running before there's any data for it to work on. In the majority of cases, you will want to set `async: false` if you want to do something with the data which is returned. If you simply want to set a value and assume it's going to work, then `async: true` makes sense.

In other words, SPServices is working fine; it's simply doing what you've asked it to do.

Comment: sorry to answer so late !!
But I tried to put async to true and async to false and it is the same probleme !!

Comment: I think you're going to have to do some debugging. GetListItems should work very, very consistently. Did you switch to $(document).ready(), as suggested by PirateEric?